# Maven dependency given but still one class not found on execution

Tags: class, maven, dependencies

I have added maven dependencies in pom.xml for cdk but still i get one error of class not found when executing the jar file.

```
dyna218-128:spark4vs laeeqahmed$ java -cp target/spark4vs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar se.uu.farmbio.spark4vs.RunPrediction
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openscience/cdk/interfaces/IAtomContainer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IAtomContainer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

**POM.XML is as under**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency><!-- SVM depedency -->          
        <groupId>tw.edu.ntu.csie</groupId>
        <artifactId>libsvm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openscience.cdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

```
    <repositories>
         <repository>
                   <id>3rdparty</id>
                   <url>https://maven.ch.cam.ac.uk/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
             </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependencies are for building project. Maven Jar Plugin is not using it when JAR id packaged. So you cant run without additional work.

Hovewer there are many solution for this. For example you can use Maven One Jar Plugin and package all dependencies into JAR - but this is not always usable
http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavensite/usage.html

You can create archive with jar-dependencies
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

You can merge all jars into one with Maven Shade Plugin
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/